# "Operation must use an updatable query" error in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am stuck with this update query:

```
UPDATE [table1] n SET n.kdo = IIf( n.old_kdo IN (SELECT u.id FROM [table2] u WHERE u.id_c<>0),"1","0")
```

it gives me "Operation must use an updatable query" error (I have all read/write permission).

I have tried bypass it by using:

```
UPDATE [table1] n SET n.kdo = IIf( n.old_kdo IN (DLookup("id", "table2", "id_c<>0")),"1","0")
```

it works, but sadly it return first match only.

Anyone have any idea how to make it right? Would be some join query better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing your subquery by a dFirst(), dCount() or similar function, and extend your criteria accordingly:

```
UPDATE [table1] n SET n.kdo = 
     iif(dCount("*", "table2", "id_c<>0 and id = " & n.old_kdo) > 0 ,"1","0")
```

Access is tricky for joins in Update queries.